# Programmatically populate DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView that I'm trying to populate using a For loop:

```
    Dim serverName As String = SQLServerName + "\" + Instance
    Dim server As Server = New Server(serverName)

    Dim Datatable1 As New DataTable

    For Each database As Database In server.Databases
        Dim row As DataRow = Datatable1.NewRow

        row("Database") = database.Name
        row("Version") = DBVersionCheck(serverName, database.Name)
        row("Status") = My.Resources.My_Image
        Datatable1.Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Datatable1
```

The DGV has been designed with the designer (columns, layout etc).
Using the above the DGV does not populate. I was using a ListView for this but I need images in a subitem so have switched to using a DGV. Any advice?

Comment: I get "Column 'Database' does not belong to table.", Do I need to programmatically create the columns within the dataTable?

Comment: Yes - you do need to add the columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the columns to the `DataTable`.

I've got some code (which is C#) but you should be able to convert it:

```
var columnSpec = new DataColumn
                    {
                        DataType = string,
                        ColumnName = "Database Name"
                    };
this.dataTable.Columns.Add(columnSpec);
```

which will add a column of type `string` with the name "Database Name".

Comment: The problem appears to be converting the image: row("Status") = My.Resources.My_Image will not work, I've created a new datacolumn with .DataType = GetType(System.Byte()).

Comment: Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <System.Drawing.Bitmap> in Status Column.  Expected type is Byte[].

Comment: @madlan - What type is `My.Resources.My_Image` and what type have you used on the `DataGridView`?

Comment: System.Drawning.Bitmap - the DataTable is .DataType = GetType(System.Byte())

Comment: If I convert the iamge to a byte with MemoryStream it works, I thought it was possible to load a bitmap directly rather than convert to a byte array?

Comment: @madlan - I'm not sure how that would work with `DataTables`.

Comment: I've made a function that returns a byte array for the given image - this works fine when added to the datatable. Thanks Chris.